# Orbot on Android x86 - Bridge not working?

Tags: orbot, android

I recently converted my old netbook to android and of course I have installed orbot 15.0.1-RC-3-PIE ( I live in China ... )

I have tried to add bridges ( same way I do on my phone ) but the bootstrap get stuck at 5%

the main problem looks this:

```
WARN: Could not launch managed proxy executable at `/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy` (No such file or directory')
```

I guess there are still not many Android x86 devices ... so I wonder if orbot is compatible with this architecture

Should I fill a bug ?